# Can't display an image and html file - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have a trouble outputting a data from database, it's a file location for an image and html file, the error I am getting is:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$image (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\resources\views\layouts\homepage.blade.php)

My code:

View:

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')

@section('content')
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
@endsection
        @section('template')
           <!-- <img src="{{asset('img/1.jpg')}}">-->
            @foreach ($templates as $template)
            {{$templates->image}}
            {{$templates->file}}
        @endforeach
        @show
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Template;

class BuilderController extends Controller
{
    function templates()
    {
        $templates = Template::all();
        return view('layouts/homepage', ['templates' => $templates]);
    }
}
```

Model: I haven't definned any relationship this is the only table is database

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Template extends Model
{
    //
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the foreach loop you have used "templateS" instead of "template" while you have defined "as template". So use {{ $template->something }}

Comment: oh my god such a simple mistake... Any idea on how I could now modify it to change from text to actual image/file so that not a text is display but the files

Comment: img src="{{ asset('img/'. $template->image )}

Comment: I get an icon that it is a image however the actual image is not displayed

Comment: The reason is the file may not have been uploaded or the extension (.jpg, .png) is not added at the file name while uploading.

Comment: You can always get the extension of an image whike uploading using: $file.getClientOriginalExtension ();

Comment: basically I have added the exact file location with the extension onto the database however since I am running locally at the moment, I want to get that file location from the database and the file from my local storage and than display it. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($templates as $template)
            {{$template->image}}
            {{$template->file}}
@endforeach
```

template not templates ^^

Comment: Yeah I have just been told that, always make these simple mistakes haha, thanks